# Plus and Minus Number in table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want number of item to add by user like :

```
-__+
```

If user add item that he add + button and increase item. so i added `textfield` to table and add two button Plus(+) and Minus(-). Here is my code  in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
 if(isPlus){
        countFruitQty++;
        cell.txtQty.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",countFruitQty];
    }
    else{
        countFruitQty--;
        if(countFruitQty > 0)
            cell.txtQty.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",countFruitQty];
        else{
            cell.txtQty.text = @"";
            countFruitQty = 0;
        }
```

But on scroll it change data to all added textField.
How to Prevent this?

Comment: Hey, could you please explain your query, I cant understand what you meant?

Comment: So is this happening in each row on your tableview, and there are multiple textifleds and buttons etc?

Comment: countFruitQty is repeat and set same number to all textField when i scroll tableField.

Comment: No its one textField in talble abd two button there. and more than 50 rows are there @JoeBenton

Comment: you don't really store the data permanently on your _model_ – but on the _view_ layer, if the view is released, of course, the data which it contains will be lost as well, if you don't have any other other place where you'd store it... and restore it from.

Comment: Are you using any data object to handle data shown in all 50 rows. Please edit the question and make your question more detailed

Answer (score 3):

You have to manage array for it,

Check below code for your reference, Hope it will help you out

```
@interface YourViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *arrMain;      // Your main array (Table row count)
    NSMutableArray *arrCounter;   // Counter array
    int a;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

       arrMain = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       arrCounter = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       a = 0;
       for (int i = 0, i < [arrMain count], i++) {

           [arrCounter addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",a]];
       }
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      cell.btnPlus.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.btnPlus addTarget:self action:@selector(click_Plus:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        cell.btnMinus.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.btnMinus addTarget:self action:@selector(click_Minus:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        cell.txtQty.text = [arrCounter objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}


-(IBAction)click_Plus:(UIButton *)sender {

    int qnt = [cell.txtQty.text intValue];
    cell. txtQty.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",++qnt];
    [arrCounter replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:cell.txtQty.text];
}

-(IBAction)click_Minus:(UIButton *)sender {

    int qnt = [cell.txtQty.text intValue];
    cell.txtQty.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",--qnt];
    [arrCounter replaceObjectAtIndex:sender.tag withObject:cell.txtQty.text];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens because when you scroll your tableview cell is reused and reset all your textfield

if you want to achieve this functionality you should use scrollview and addSuview when you need